# Почему sql запрос ничего не возвращает?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite, запрос

В Базе данных есть таблица `recepts` структура:

```
CREATE TABLE `receptes` ( `recept` TEXT, `ingridient` TEXT )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но sql выражение:

```
select recept from receptes
where ingridient = "Вода" and ingridient = "Сахар";
```

ничего не возвращает, почему?

Comment: Потому что нельзя одновременно быть и водой и сахаром. Поменяйте условие на OR: `where (ingridient = "Вода" or ingridient = "Сахар");` Представьте себе аналогичную проверку в коде `if (x == 10 and x == 12)`. Давайте закроем вопрос как "вызван опечаткой"?

Comment: еще можно сделать `where ingridient IN ("вода", "сахар")`

Comment: @AK Да, действительно глупая ошибка.

Comment: @Alexxosipov большое спасибо, это именно то чего я хотел добиться